# Can someone help me fix the error, "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'num1' of Program.Year (int)

Tags: c#, subroutine

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Year(int num1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a year.");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (num1 % 4 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is a leap year mate.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return num1;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Year());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary parameter on `public static int Year(int num1)` ... you don't need `int num1` because you don't even use it. But the error message is because you called Year without giving it a parameter. Your parenthesis were empty:

`Year()`

It would work if you used `Year(0)` or gave it some kind of other int parameter, but as you're not even using the parameter you should delete it:

`public static int Year() { /* ... your code here */ }`

But your error message is what you get whenever you try to call methods or constructors without supplying the proper arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an input parameter in Year method. Remove it and try this

```
          public static int Year()
          {
    
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a not leap year.");
            var num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (num1 % 4 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is a leap year mate. Try again");
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return num1;
         }

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Year());
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```